# Update wordpress files with FTP

Tags: wordpress, ftp

I installed wordpress on the server manually using filezilla. Now if i edit my wordpress website will it get automatically updated on my pc or do i need to download the changes manually? I want to have a backup of my website in case something goes wrong.

Comment: It will inform you and show you notification in wp admin panel whenever new update is available. Then you will need to update it manually. But it is good practice to take backup on some regular interval so in future if any other issue happen on site then you can use backup.

Comment: okk, but how will i know which files are changed and need to be downloaded?

Comment: Please check my update answer.

Comment: Because WordPress is a database driven CMS, it might not be physical files that are changed when you make "edits" (it depends what you do) - the changes might only be in the database, which you can't simply download using FileZilla without first making a backup of the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it won't. Filezilla doesn't work 2-way automatically. When you update your WordPress site the changes won't be downloaded in your PC automaticaly. Your best option is to use github or to backup your whole website when making changes.

Comment: so the purpose of ftp is just to upload images and other files?

Comment: yep, absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress will not update automatically until you do it. Whenever new version of wordpress is available , it will notify you in your wp admin panel and then you can update if you want.

You can update wordpress via filezilla by overwriting files only if you know which files need to update to get new version.

I suggest that always take backup of your site & database on some regular interval like weekly , daily whatever is suitable for you so in future if you face any issue in site then you can use recent backup.

For local files in your pc , you will have to compare code of files one by one with latest version files.

Here you can follow steps that How you can update wordpress via FTP : [Update Wordpress via FTP](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-manually-update-wordpress-using-ftp/)

Comment: The OP was asking about the reverse - updating his local files when updating WordPress

Comment: @Barnettt - I see , Just updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

before making changes to your wordpress
go to the wp-admin setting and export the backup

or you can also of course backup  using the ftp to your local pc

remember to export the mysql db data also